# How to call code form obfuscated dll?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I have a dll, which is the important part of my program. I've obfuscated it, but how can I call methods from it? Before this I called them by name (string).

Comment: Eschew obfuscation and surplusage, espouse elucidation

Comment: Are you calling via reflection? If not, then you should be able to call any public members as usual as these should not be changed by obfuscating.

Comment: The (public) interfaces and types should still be the same. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obfuscation doesn't change the public method names. You should just be able to use it as normal.

What do you mean you called them by name(string)? String's shouldn't have anything to do with calling methods.

Comment: with Type.GetMethod(), but I guess they're not encrypted since they're public.

Comment: Okay they should be called the same thing. But is there a reason you're using reflection to call methods instead of just referencing the assembly and creating the classes?

Comment: `Obfuscation doesn't change the public method names.` That sounds like over generalization. There is no reason not to change public method names provides the obfuscater knows all call sites of that function. And that's often possible if you obfuscate a whole application.

Comment: No reason, I guess I'll just use an interface.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, you may be right. I had always assumed that it wouldn't change them, otherwise how do you call them? But yeah, you could have an obfuscater that did change them (and to hell with any callers that weren't obfuscated at the same time).

Comment: @blez. Reflection should be avoided if possible. It's slow an prone to breakage if you refactor things. No need for interfaces (although they couldn't hurt), just create the classes like you would any other class.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a static language, meaning that calling object.SomeMethod() will compile to IL and it will be nothing like the source code. However, if you are using reflection for calling the method (by hard-coding the method name in a string), the obfuscation will change the method name you are trying to call, so the call will fail. One thing that can be done is to exclude the method to be obfuscated, depending from tool to tool.